# Cancel an infinite loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to timeout a function in case it has an infinite loop. But the below does not work. Any idea why and how to fix it?

```
setTimeout(clearValues,1000);

function clearValues(){
    i=0;
    alert("hi "+i);
}

i=19
function infin(){
    while(i>0){
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    }
    alert("Done");
}

infin();
```

In the below case, I get the alert displayed ( a bit later than expected ) and the console statements continue printing even after the alert. That means setTimeout did not wait for the loop to end in this case. Any explanation for this?

```
setTimeout(clearValues,500);

function clearValues(){
    alert("clear");
}


function infin(){
for(i=0;i<10000;){
    i=i+0.3;
    console.log(i);
}
}

infin();
```

Comment: On which action are u calling these functions??

Comment: No specific action. This just runs as a script.

Comment: the second example does work only after the loop finished.

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` works asynchronously, means it will run after 1000ms **and** the previous event loop is completed. Since the while loop will never be completed, the callback will never be called.

Add a condition to the loop if you want to exit it.

Comment: It probably has to do with the implementation of console.log. if you'll test it in different browser you'll probably get different results.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might be to use interval:

```
var code = function(){ 
              console.log('tick'); 
           };
var clock = setInterval(code, 200);
```

When you don't need it anymore:

```
clearInterval(clock);
```

Comment: OP is using `setTimeout` and not `setInterval`

Comment: Sorry but what OP stands for?

Comment: It is the person who asks the question

Comment: @JeanF. OP - Original Poster

Answer (score 0):

It works, when you made the `infin` call with a slightly different change.

```js
var i = 0;
setTimeout(clearValues, 1000);
var interval = setInterval(infin, 0);

function clearValues() {
    out("clear");
    clearInterval(interval);
}

function infin() {
    if (i < 10000) {                    // if you be shure that you
        i++;
        out(i);
    } else {                            // never reach the limit,
         clearInterval(interval);       // you can remove the four
    }                                   // commented lines
}

function out(s, pre) {
    var descriptionNode = document.createElement('div');
    if (pre) {
        var preNode = document.createElement('pre');
        preNode.innerHTML = s + '<br>';
        descriptionNode.appendChild(preNode);
    } else {
        descriptionNode.innerHTML = s + '<br>';
    }
    document.getElementById('out').appendChild(descriptionNode);
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```